# Translate command output to dictionary in specific case

Tags: ansible

I have following task in ansible role:

```
- name: get answer from server
  command: "curl http://my_server:8888" 
  register: response
```

Now, `response.stdout` looks exactly like:

```
Server: 10.8.7.1
Domain: com
State: Health
Type: B

Server: 10.8.7.2
Domain: eu
State: Health
Type: A

Server: 10.8.7.3
Domain: com
State: Health
Type: C

Server: 10.8.7.4
Domain: com
State: Bad
Type: C
```

How to translate it into list of dictionaries (like `{"Server": "10.8.7.1", "Domain": "com","State": "Health","Type": "B"}`) ?

I considered writing my own python module, however I believe that you can know some more elegant way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python convert a paritcular string to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827550/python-convert-a-paritcular-string-to-dict)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about elegant, but if that output from `curl` is stable and predictable you could do this:

```
- name: get answer from server
  shell: curl http://my_server:8888 | sed -e 's/^/  /' -e 's/  Server/- Server/'
  register: response
- debug:
    var: response.stdout | from_yaml
```

- Note because you are introducing a pipe, you need to switch to `shell` from `comannd`
- We are using the `sed` command to format the output into something that looks like YAML
- As a result, we can pass the `response.stdout` into the `from_yaml` filter, which will decode the string into a list of dictionaries

Again, not sure about elegant. Feels just a little bit dirty to me, but hey, gets the job done :)

As for the clean way to do it - if it is possible, get the file on remote server generated in some structured format (ideally JSON) and then you can use the Ansible `uri` module to read it.